# Logstash - How to filter different types logs file coming through filebeat

Tags: logstash

I've two log files on my remote host sample.log and example.log, both of them contains different pattern logs. How can I easily use different filter for each log type in Logstash? Can someone give me an example please. I am using filebeat to ship these logs to Logstash.

My Logstash.conf file is something like below.

```
   input {
   beats {
   port => 5044
   client_inactivity_timeout => 599
   ssl => true
   ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
   ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
   }
```

Thanks,
Charan

Comment: The logs sent by filebeat should have a field (`source`) with the filename. Then use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) on this field.

Comment: could you please give me an example if possible

Answer (score 0):

In your filter, you can check the value of a field before you try to match your patterns. There's a `file` field that shows the source file:

```
filter {
    if [file] == "/var/log/sample.log" {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => [ "/etc/logstash/patterns" ]
            match => {
                "message" => "%{SOME_PATTERN}"
            }
            add_tag => [ "processed" ]
        }
    }
}
```